# Deserialize json to java using jackson - issues with special characters

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jackson, dropwizard

I am using jackson (jersey and jetty) for my REST webservices - and all is going well.  But I have a requirement to include a special character in one of the name value pairs in json post request. i.e.
json request (in post body)-

```
{
  "id": "1",
   "print-color" : "red"
}
```

//"-" in "print-color" is giving problems.

Now inside my corresponding java bean for this object `Item.java` class, I cant make a property with name print-color (because "-" is not allowed).  How do I deal with it in mapping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try following in Java POJO:

```
@JsonProperty("print-color")
```

Comment: That works! just one more question, in my response (i.e. @produces json) how could I control the order in which these properties go... e.g how can i ensure that "print-color" always go as 2nd element and "id" goes in as 1st element. thanks.

Comment: You can use @JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "print-color" }) to keep the order. Can you please accept the answer