# Handling a JSON field with a special character in its name in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, special-characters

I need to parse JSON in Java (using Jackson, at the moment) where there is a field that has a(n) '`@`' in it as the name of the property -- e.g.

```
{
           "@type": "hotelResult",
           "f": "Blehbleh",
           "d": "BlahBlah"
}
```

Since using the POJO that has a structure matching the expected structure of the input, including the name, I'm wondering how to handle that '`@type`' field (it won't compile just by naming it that, of course).

Without the '`@`' there, I would define the body of the class as:

```
public class HotelGeographyType {

    String type;

    String f;
    String d;

        // etc.
}
```

Suggestions on how I would handle the 'type' field coming back with that @ sign?

Comment: answered here, looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962698/deserialize-json-to-java-using-jackson-issues-with-special-characters

Comment: Well, you could always just process the JSON.